# Animating ListView row deletions with React Native LayoutAnimation

Tags: listview, animation, react-native, layout-animation

I'm having difficulty animating the deletion of a row from ListView using LayoutAnimation.

Since LayoutAnimation.spring preset animation handles view updates with a spring and view creations with a fade, I expected the bottom existing rows to spring upwards after the deletion. Instead, they fade in.

Using RN 0.18.1

```
let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
var movies = [movie1, movie2, movie3, movie4, movie5];

...

renderRow(row) {
  return <MovieRow key={row.movieId} />
}

...

// immutable delete of element in reducer (redux)
movies = movies.slice(0, 2).concat(movies.slice(3));

...

LayoutAnimation.spring();
this.setState({
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(movies)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The latest `react-native` already support animation on deletion. I did something like:

```
const CustomLayoutLinear = {
  duration: 300,
  create: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
    property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity
  },
  update: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut
  },
  delete: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
    property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity
  }
};
```

Only create or delete will trigger opacity easing in and out. Update the component just do easeIn and ease out.

Then hook the customLayoutLinear when mounting the component

```
  LayoutAnimation.configureNext(CustomLayoutLinear);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like LayoutAnimation doesn't support deletion yet.

> Note: LayoutAnimation works for Create and Update layout events. Deletion is not supported yet. Notice when circles are removed there is no animation.

Check this: https://medium.com/@Jpoliachik/react-native-s-layoutanimation-is-awesome-4a4d317afd3e#.9cdaqazay

**Edit:**
Deletion is supported now:

**Android**: [0.28 release notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.28.0)

**iOS**: [0.26 release notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.26.0)

Comment: it seems it does now! https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6779 (But I haven't been able to test it yet ..)

Comment: Deletion seems to be supported but I can't seem to make it work. Anyone how got this working?